# Pytesseract: FileNotFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been having some problems with Pytesser using this code to test it:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('pic.png')
img.load()
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Run on Python 3.4 in Windows

When run I get the error originating from the Pytesseract module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Gamer/Documents/Python/Bot/test.py", line 6, in <module>
      text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
      config=config)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
   proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am new to installing modules and this may have originated from a bad install or setup of Tesseract-OCR or the module.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

-Niall

Comment: Is `tesseract` from Tesseract-OCR in your PATH? If not either add it to your PATH environment vairable or use [this](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L21) variable to give a custom path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have any issues with installing tesseract but I leveraged the Tesseract at UB Mannheim installer:

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

You will also need to install pytesseract:

pip3.6 install pytesseract

It appears that Python is having an issue finding the location of the image.  I would recommend using a variable set with the path to the image to rule out any PATH related issues.  Here is an example:

```
#Path to image folder    
src_path = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents\\OCR\\"

#Run OCR on image    
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "pic.png"))

#Print OCR result
print (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As 'st0le' commented it turned out it was the path for the OCR-Tesseract needed to be correctly defined, not the path of the image.

I thought I'd just clear this up for anyone else who has a similar problem as I have got this working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  from PIL import Image
  import pytesseract

  img = Image.open('path/pic.png')
  img.load()
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  print(text)
```

Include whole path to the image!!